# Keep colored logs when piping output with docker-compose v2.5.0

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose 1.25.3 I used to pipe the output of logs. E.g.,

```
docker-compose logs -ft | cat
```

The output is colored as expected.

In docker-compose 2.5.0, this does not happen anymore. Native output `docker-compose logs -ft` is still colored. However, when I run:

```
docker-compose logs -ft | cat
```

The piped output is not colored anymore. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect that if logs is not writing directly to a console, then the formatting is also suppressed.  Try the command without the pipe to cat, ie `docker-compose logs -ft`.

Comment: Logs without pipe are colored